# In Windows, how does a per-user install happen for users who lack install privileges?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

My users typically work on locked-down workstations. They lack administrator privileges and cannot install software for themselves. In the past, I've designed my applications to be installed per-machine, not per-user. An administrator installs my application on a workstation, and everyone using that workstation can then use the application.

Now I'm considering switching to a per-user install, but I don't know how that would work in my user environment. Is there a way for an administrator to say "Use my privileges to install this application not for me, but for user X?" Does the administrator have to do one user install at a time, or is there a way to do a batch of installs all at once? In a nutshell, am I making things easier, harder, or impossible for the IT staff? Does any of this depend on my installer? (I'm using Windows Installer.)

Comment: First of all why you decided to go for per-user installation?

Comment: I haven't decided to change, but I'm considering it. Part of the reason is to facilitate per-user licenses. Another part of the reason is that the official word from Microsoft is "In Windows 7 and later, we strongly recommend you install applications per user rather than per machine." (See [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Comment: Also see microsoft docs: [installation context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installation-context)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as "install privileges".  The only reason that a non-admin user cannot install a conventional application is that the installer typically (a) wants to put the application files in `Program Files` which requires admin privilege; and (b) wants to create a registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` and write to it.  [Still older installers may also want to write files into `system32`, make other global registry changes, and so on, but this is discouraged nowadays.]

A per-user install happens without any administrator privilege.  The application files are put in the user's own space, e.g., inside the application data folder, and the application's registry key is created in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` instead of `HKLM`.  This means the user can install the application themselves without the admin's assistance or permission.  [Actually an administrator *can* lock down the system in such a way that users can't install their own applications, but this isn't common outside of the stricter enterprise environments.]

If an application only supports per-user installation, there is no way for the administrator to install the application on the user's behalf.  Each user has to run the installer themselves.  [Of course a skilled administrator could automate this so that, for example, the installer runs automatically when the user logs in.]

Whether per-user installation makes things easier or harder on the IT staff depends entirely on the scenario.  However, many enterprise sysadmins are unhappy about per-user applications.  There are also scenarios (roaming profiles, for example) where per-user applications may either malfunction or cause other problems such as excessive network load or disk quota issues.  [And in some enterprises they will be locked out altogether due to software restriction policy, AppLocker, and/or third-party equivalents.]

It is possible for an installer to support both per-machine and per-user installation, so this is usually the best option; alternatively, like Google Chrome, you could provide separate per-user and a per-machine installers for the same application.

If I understand correctly, Windows Installer makes it particularly easy to provide an installer that can do both per-machine and per-user installations.  Most .msi files that support per-user installations will also support per-machine installations via the [`ALLUSERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.  I'm not sure whether the developer needs to do anything in particular to make this work.

Comment: Mr. Johnston, Thank you for this well-written answer. Everything I hoped to learn is contained in these key points: 1) "A per-user install happens without any administrator privilege"; 2) "If an application only supports per-user installation, there is no way for the administrator to install the application on the user's behalf"; and 3) "There are ... scenarios ... where per-user applications may either malfunction or cause other problems."

Comment: @Cyro, just in case a real-world example is useful to you or to other readers: Google Chrome, by default, installs itself per-user.  In our teaching labs, we use roaming profiles and the computers are configured to automatically delete the local copies when the user logs off.  If a Google Chrome is installed per-user, it works, but only until the user logs off; when you log back in, Chrome is non-functional (because the files have been deleted).  With older versions of Chrome, you couldn't even re-install it successfully, though newer versions may have fixed that issue, I'm not sure.